# How can I choose phone number in INSendPaymentIntent

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios10, sirikit

In my application I need to send payments using users' phone number (not users' contact name). So if the user in contacts has 2 phone numbers, user has to choose one of the numbers (like in phone call intent).

In function `func resolvePayee(forSendPayment intent: INSendPaymentIntent, with completion: @escaping (INPersonResolutionResult) -> Void)` I see only user's name, surname, but I don't have phone number. Even `intent.payee.personHandle always == nil`

Comment: Hi! did u find solution how to choose number if the recipient has two numbers? I have the same problem. If u solved it could u please post an answer to your question?

Comment: @dasha , I added answer, I think it's not the best way, but it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this work around (just add number to contact name when I display them). Here is the full code of resolvePayee function:

```
func resolvePayee(forSendPayment intent: INSendPaymentIntent, with completion: @escaping (INPersonResolutionResult) -> Void) {

        print("start resolving payee")

        if let payee = intent.payee, payee.displayName.length > 0 {

            // search proper phone number if we chose between these numbers before
            var foundPhoneNumberInBuferNumbers: String? = nil
            if let arrayOfSavedPhones = PaymentIntentHandler.resolvePayeeHelp_offeredPhoneNumbersFor1Contact {
                for phone in arrayOfSavedPhones {
                    if payee.displayName.hasSuffix(phone) {
                        foundPhoneNumberInBuferNumbers = phone
                        break
                    }
                }
                if foundPhoneNumberInBuferNumbers == nil { // if we didn't manage to find this number that means that we have a new request for a new contact, so we don't need to remember number in buffer anymore
                    print("can't find phone number for \(payee.displayName), so we remove all buffer numbers = \(PaymentIntentHandler.resolvePayeeHelp_offeredPhoneNumbersFor1Contact)")
                    PaymentIntentHandler.resolvePayeeHelp_offeredPhoneNumbersFor1Contact = nil
                }
            }

            let searchName = foundPhoneNumberInBuferNumbers != nil ? payee.displayName.replacingOccurrences(of: " " + foundPhoneNumberInBuferNumbers!, with: "") : payee.displayName

            Singleton.sharedInstance.contactsService_getPhoneContacts(contactIdentifiresToFetch: nil, matchingName: searchName, showAlert: false, completionBlock: { (havePermission, customContactsMatchingName) in
                if !havePermission { // user didn't grant permissions
                    print("unsupported because don't have permissions")
                    completion(INPersonResolutionResult.unsupported())
                    return
                }

                switch customContactsMatchingName.count {
                case 2 ... Int.max: // user has to choose
                    let arrayOfPersons = customContactsMatchingName.map({ (phoneBookContact) -> INPerson in
                        return phoneBookContact.inSiriPerson()
                    })
                    print("disambiguation between several contacts")
                    completion(INPersonResolutionResult.disambiguation(with: arrayOfPersons))
                case 1:
                    let contactCustom = customContactsMatchingName[0]
                    switch contactCustom.phoneNumbers.count {
                    case 0:
                        print("unsupported because don't have phone numbers")
                        completion(INPersonResolutionResult.unsupported())
                    case 1:
                        print("success")
                        completion(INPersonResolutionResult.success(with: contactCustom.inSiriPerson()))
                    case 2 ... Int.max:

                        print("now we have a uniq contact, but several phone numbers")

                        if foundPhoneNumberInBuferNumbers == nil { // we need user to choose between several phone numbers

                            var arrayOfStringNumbers = [String]()
                            var arrayOfPersonsToChoose = [INPerson]()
                            for phoneNumber in contactCustom.phoneNumbers {
                                let numberOnlyDigits = Singleton.sharedInstance.phone_getPhoneOnlyDigits(phoneNumber.number)
                                let formattedNumber = Singleton.sharedInstance.phone_getFormattedPhone("+" + numberOnlyDigits, allowLetters: false)
                                arrayOfStringNumbers.append(formattedNumber)
                                let personHandler = INPersonHandle(value: formattedNumber, type: .phoneNumber)
                                let person = INPerson(personHandle: personHandler, nameComponents: nil, displayName: payee.displayName + " " + formattedNumber, image: nil, contactIdentifier: contactCustom.id, customIdentifier: formattedNumber)
                                arrayOfPersonsToChoose.append(person)
                            }

                            PaymentIntentHandler.resolvePayeeHelp_offeredPhoneNumbersFor1Contact = arrayOfStringNumbers

                            print("disambiguation in one contact between several phones")
                            completion(INPersonResolutionResult.disambiguation(with: arrayOfPersonsToChoose))
                        }
                        else {

                            // found proper phone number
                            print("success after choosing bufer number")
                            let personHandle = INPersonHandle(value: foundPhoneNumberInBuferNumbers!, type: .phoneNumber)
                            let displayName = payee.displayName.replacingOccurrences(of: " " +  foundPhoneNumberInBuferNumbers!, with: "")
                            completion(INPersonResolutionResult.success(with: INPerson(personHandle: personHandle, nameComponents: nil, displayName: displayName, image: nil, contactIdentifier: nil, customIdentifier: personHandle.value)))
                        }


                    default:
                        print("unsupported: can't happen")
                        completion(INPersonResolutionResult.unsupported())
                    }
                case 0:
                    print("unsupported because can't find this contact in phonebook = \(searchName), contacts in buffer = \(PaymentIntentHandler.resolvePayeeHelp_offeredPhoneNumbersFor1Contact)")
                    completion(INPersonResolutionResult.unsupported())
                default:
                    print("unsupported: can't happen")
                    completion(INPersonResolutionResult.unsupported())
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            print("needsValue")
            PaymentIntentHandler.resolvePayeeHelp_offeredPhoneNumbersFor1Contact = nil
            completion(INPersonResolutionResult.needsValue())
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank u for reply! And what exactly Siri asks when you have a persons with several numbers? "Which number do u want to choose?" or "which name?"

Comment: I don't remember, but not "which name". Smth like "choose between" (can't try right now, because I removed siri support temporary, because I had problems to upload archive to apple, because there were issues with cocoa pods for me)

Comment: maybe it's not the best solution, but I didn't find better as well :D thank u!